# Hide camera preview in OpenCV android

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera

I am building this application where I need to get video with the camera and process it with openCV as well as show a view with 3D graphics being renderered in it.I am using two fragments. One for previewing the camera. And one for the 3D graphics.The problem is the 3d graphics view has to be fullscreen. I don't want the camera preview at all. I can show them side by side using linear layout. But I cannot totally hide the preview and make the 3d scene take up the whole screen. Even using relative layout causes the camera preview to tear through the 3d graphics view.
Simply put it, if the camera preview is not being shown, the `CvCameraViewListener2.onCameraFrame()` method is not called. And without that I don't receive any new frames to process.

Comment: Generally speaking, you can use FrameLayout and put the camera preview under (in terms of z-order) the 3D scene. Unfortunately, this is not reliable. When you resume the activity, it will sometimes reveal the camera preview. The ultimate solution is to use SurfaceTexture and *not* render this texture in your 3D scene, but this is not how OpenCV native camera works. You can open the camera in Java and pass the preview frames to (native) OpenCV for image processing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem got solved. I really don't know how it got solved though. I woke up the next day and tried running the project and it ran perfectly without requiring to change anything.